# Logical multiplication of matrices in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the a matrix **A** and a vector **B**, where the matrix **A** is filled with *0*'s and *1*'s, and the vector **B** is filled with strings. I want to execute the following operation:

```
A = np.array([[1,1,0],[0,1,1],[0,0,1]])
B = np.array(['a','b','c'])
```

and the result must be:

```
R = np.array(['a'+'b', 'b'+'c', 'c'])
```

Is it possible to do it with `numpy`?

Comment: i only used numpy. See my answer

Comment: Should that be `R = np.array(['ab', 'bc', 'c'])`, or am I missing something?

Comment: Indeed this should be `R = np.array(['ab', 'bc', 'c'])` .see my answer. cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way if you define your array `b` with `dtype = object`:

```
b = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=object)
```

Then it is simply a `dot` product:

```
a.dot(b)
#array(['ab', 'bc', 'c'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Nice! Of course, without changing the defintion of `B`, `R = A.dot(B.astype(object))` works too.

Comment: This is about 7 times faster than my solution… well done @Brenlla

Answer (score 2):

The best I could come up with is:

```
def np_add_charrarays(*arrays):
    """Concatenate n char arrays together with n > 2"""
    res = np.core.defchararray.add(*arrays[:2])
    for arr in arrays[2:]:
        res = np.core.defchararray.add(res, arr)
    return res

np_add_charrarays(*np.core.defchararray.multiply(B, A).T)

# output: array(['ab', 'bc', 'c'], dtype='<U3')
```

I'm not really sure if whether it is faster than going standard *pure* python. Help yourself with some `timeit`s.

Answer (score 2):

Actually yes, there is a way using numpy. Use `numpy.where`:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,1,0],[0,1,1],[0,0,1]])
B = np.array(['a','b','c'])

R = np.where(A,B,'')

print(R)
[['a' 'b' '']
 ['' 'b' 'c']
 ['' '' 'c']]

R.astype(object).sum(axis=1)
['ab', 'bc', 'c']
```

Comment: no. OP is after `np.array(['a'+'b', 'b'+'c', 'c'])` as stated in the question

Comment: I don't understand: `'a' + 'b'` has to be `'ab'`, surely -- it can't remain unevaluated, can it?

Comment: @seralouk nice answer, if the OP wants to concatenate the strings, simply  `np.where(A,B,'').astype(object).sum(axis=1)` should work

Comment: exactly. I just provided a different answer using numpy where. Your solution is also nice.

Comment: @seralouk All good post-edit :-) Might I suggest adding back in explicitly the fact that `R` itself is `[['a' 'b' ''], ['' 'b' 'c'], ['' '' 'c']]`, just to make it even clearer what both `np.where` and then the final operation are doing.